# How can I open Python files in IDLE from Windows?

Tags: windows-vista, python

I'm new to Python. I use Python 2.7 and I am running Windows Vista (64-bit). How do I make it when I click on `.py` scripts... that it opens up in IDLE so I can edit it a snap? Ya know... without having to open IDLE by itself.

I got all the way to `C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib` but I don't see the IDLE application.

Then when I do right-click and "Default open with" and select the `idle.bat` file.. I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At least for Python 3.1 (it shouldn't be any different for 2.7), IDLE is located in `C:\Python31\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat`.

So to make it open Python scripts, right-click a script, go to **Open with** → **Choose default program**, click **Browse**, browse to `C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib`, and select `idle.bat` (the extension might not show depending on your Windows settings). Remember to check the **Always use selected program to open this kind of file** button if it isn't checked already.

Comment: I can't...  I get this error :(

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/QTsEQ.jpg

Comment: Choose "Select a program from a list of installed programs", and then click Browse and follow the rest of my instructions.

Comment: I did... THAT's the error I get when I follow those intructions.

Comment: Do you ever get to a screen like this? ---> http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/8144/browsescreen.png

Comment: No, I did not. I go to pythonw.exe, click OK, and I do NOT receive that python thingy. :( GRRR VISTA!!

Comment: Try right clicking on python to get the file location. Then look for the "Lib" folder in that location.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 Pro 64bit after installing `python-3.5.1-amd64.exe` had the same issue no edit context after install.

To correct: Right click .py file, open with Choose default program ... then assigned to: `c:\users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\pythonw.exe` and selected "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" & the .py files changed to the Python IDE icon & the edit context menu started showing up.

Comment: That path helped me find it, but the program to open with is `idle.bat` in the `idlelib` folder.

Answer (score 2):

The Python installer usually creates an `"Edit with IDLE"` context menu entry for `.py` files.

If it's not there on your machine, you can add it with the following registry file.

- Save it as `edit_with_idle.reg`
- Edit it and replace `C:\\Python27` with the correct path to Python on your machine.
- Import it into your registry by double-clicking it and confirming the warning message.

Reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Edit with IDLE]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Edit with IDLE\command]
@="\"C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe\" \"C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib\\idle.pyw\" -e \"%1\""
```

An `"Edit with IDLE"` option should now appear when you right-click `.py` files.

If it doesn't, make sure that `.py` files are registered correctly: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.py\(Default)` should contain `Python.File`.

Answer (score 2):

The below steps will work for **Python 3.9.6**.

1. Right click the .py file and click *Open with* → *Choose another app*.

   [image: Screenshot of right-click in File Epxlorer]
2. In the *How do you want to open this file?* dialogue box, make sure that the *Always use this app to open .py files* option is checked. Click on *More apps ↓*.

   [image]
3. Scroll till the bottom and click on *Look for another app on this PC*.

   [image]
4. In the *Open with...* dialogue box, go to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\idlelib` and click on `idle.bat`. Click on the *Open* button.

   **Note**:

   - Use your username in place of `username`.
   - Depending upon the version of Python, the file location will change.

   [image]

---

Now, all the .py files will be opened by default by IDLE.

Comment: Probably my answer is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/a/1420306. Reviewers, please decide what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have "Edit with IDLE" among your options when you right-click a .py file? that should be IDLE's default behavior, maybe it can change according to some installation/system settings. I wouldn't set IDLE as the default program to open .py files, that's python's task. Also that would imply you don't get them executed when you double click them or type their extension-complete name in the command line.

If what i said above doesn't work for you, you could add the IDLE path you mentioned to the Path system variable in Windows, so you can type in the command line:

> idle file_you_want_to_open.py 
>   **or** 
>   idle.py file_you_want_to_open.py

Once you add the IDLE path to the Path system variable you can also lauch IDLE typing "idle" in the box you get from windowsbutton-R. As a plus, you could add the .py estension to the PATHEXT system variable to have python scripts execute "by name only" like executables, system commands, compiled programs or whatever you call it.

note: this started as a comment, then got somehow ...lengthy. I believe you can find all i said, just better, in many python tutorials around the internet.

EDIT to fit your edited question: my previuos answer should solve your problem even if your system is not properly set to run .pyw files, anyway just choose "select a program from a list...", if python is not there look for it in its folder. It seems a matter of having python "linked" with .pyw files, like it's supposed to be. Just let me repeat: you don't want to have .py files open in IDLE by default, look at my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is a module ,i.e. has Python functions which require  arguments, then using F5 in the IDLE editor window won't work.  Perhaps need to create another file which calls the function with arguments and use F5 to execute that. Use import from filename import * to import the module with the function into this second script and then call the function with its arguments.